# Laravel delete method not allowed

Tags: php, laravel

I am writing a laravel api and when I try to make delete and post requests I keep getting a method not allowed exception.  Where should I be looking to diagnose this problem?

I have read though most of the other posts on this issue and here is what I have tried/looked at.
• Made sure the route syntax was correct

• Made sure it didn't conflict with another route

• Made sure I was using the correct route (ran php artisan route:list to 
  double check)

• Modified the .htaccess folder (maybe I did this incorrectly) to allow GET, POST, PUT, DELETE

Here is what the route looks like in api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
Route::delete('delete/{id}', 'LoginController@delete');
Route::get('stuff', 'LoginController@index');
Route::get('stuff1/{Username}', 'LoginController@show');
```

here is the function in the controller

```
 public function delete(Request $request, $id) {

        $user = Login::find($id);
        $user->delete();
        return "204";
    }
```

here is my .htaccess

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

 <Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
 Allow from all
</Limit>
</IfModule>
```

I can get around this issue by changing Route::delete() to Route::get() and achieve the same functionality but this doesn't seem like standard practice.

Comment: You can see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers

Comment: Please can you show how you're making the request i.e. the form and/or the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set ajax type POST but send a parameter named _method with value delete like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:{
         _method:"DELETE"
        },
        url: productRoute,
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : productToken }
    });
```

Or because you use laravel html form helper so it generates _method hidden input automatically so you'd better send all your form inputs such as token and method like this:

```
 function()
{

    var formData=$('#yourForm').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: productRoute,
        data:formData
    })
});
```

Comment: This is only relevant if you are using an HTML form, because HTML forms don't support the DELETE method type. When using an API with a proper client, you can use any HTTP method.